# Javascript not working correctly in my Joomla Article

Tags: html, joomla

I'm trying to add a little funcionality to one of my Joomla article. The functionality is quite simple, when you click on a string, a html shows. I had made an standalone HTML and it's working.

Now I'm trying to include the code on my Joomla article, but its not working. This is what I added to the source code of the article.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showItem').click(function(){
                    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
                    jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
            });
    }); 
</script>

<!-- BUTTONS  -->
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="showItem" target="1">First string</a><br>
    <a class="showItem" target="2">Second string</a><br>
</div>

<!-- Shows HTML page when you click in 'First string' -->
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display: none">
    <div id="m1" style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px;">
        <object type="text/html" data="http://show_a_html_page.html"
                style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
        </object>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Shows HTML page when you click in 'Second string' -->
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display: none">
    <div id="m2" style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px;">
        <object type="text/html" data="http://show_a_html_page.html"
                style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's not the problem of the editor (aka it's not removing the `<script>` tags).

Do I've to change something in my script in order to make this work?

In case this can be interesting, after adding the code as `Source Code` in my post, this is what shows up the TinyMCE. It adds some `<p>` to the code as well as a `/ <![CDATA[`. Is this right?

```
<p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>// <![CDATA[
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showItem').click(function(){
                    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
                    jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
            });
    });
// ]]></script>
</p>
```

Comment: This will help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995404/how-to-use-different-version-of-jquery-on-a-js-file/33995498#33995498

Comment: thank you, but where's the conflict in my code?

Comment: which version of joomla you're using? Inspect there, you may find another jquery loading in your page...

Comment: Inspecting the code, the `jquerys` are loading are: `jquery.min.js` ( jQuery v1.10.2), `jquery-noconflict.js` and `jquery-migrate.min.js`

Comment: So, you may try with linked answer. Or just put one jquery lib.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. I added `<script>jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>` at the top of my code, and after that all the code I added on the 1st post and it's not working either.

Comment: Are you sure you load this before loading jquery?

Comment: If I post at the top of the code, it should load first, right? This is the code: http://pastebin.com/n4efRRe6

Comment: That should be okay. any error?

Comment: Yes! `TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function` on the line `jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();`

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot @BhojendraNepal for your help!

Comment: @Borja - You don't need to import another jQuery library. Joomla already imports jQuery. By importing it twice, you'll get conflict errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BhojendraNepal stated, it was a conflict problem. I fixed it by adding `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` to the function.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery('.showItem').click(function(){
                    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
                    jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

**EDIT:** The marked as duplicate question doesn't provide an answer to the question. As that answer stated, I added `<script>jQuery.noConflict(true);//remove jquery</script>` before loading my `jquery` but it didn't worked:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict(true);//remove jquery</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showItem').click(function(){
                    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
                    jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

Just adding  `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` inside the function worked perfectly.

Comment: You should have upvoted the linked answer and deleted your post...

Comment: Using the code of the link of your comment does not provide an answer to the question as I stated on the comments, adding `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` to the code does, so I posted it.

Comment: Its just a haaahahahaha for us....